# Asana-math + LuaTeX : missing greeks/arrows

Tags: pdf, fontspec, luatex

After recent update of Asana-Math (packaged for MiKTeX on 2011-10-11) I noted that Greek letters and various arrows disappear from PDF file after it was saved from within Adobe Acrobat 10 (via the menu File | Save As | PDF...). I use such method of saving file to reduce its size. Asana-math font is loaded as follows:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

Note that the problem appears only if (1) my document is compiled with LuaLaTeX and only if (2) Asana-math font is loaded. XeLaTeX or STIX fonts work fine. I am sure that this problem did not exist before I updated Asana-Math a week ago (on 2011-10-28) since every week I compile new lecture for students and all previous lectures are OK.

Having opened PDF file in ordinary text editor, I see that the word `asana` disappears after saving PDF file from Acrobat. It means that Acrobat removes Asana-math font from the file.

**But why?**

**Update**: I located a table in my book that caused the trouble. Here is minimal example extracted from that table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Asana Math}    % damaged
    %\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}  % OK
    %\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % OK

\begin{document}%
    Fuel $T_{Br}$ $T_{\min}$ $\min(P_{Br}/P_{fus})$ \\
    ${D}{T}$ 2.7  39.4 $5{,}3\times 10^{-3}$ \\
    ${D}{D}$ 57.7 553 $4{,}1\times 10^{-1}$   \\
    ${D}[3]{He}$ 29.0 152 $1{,}4\times10^{-1}$ \\
    ${p}[11]{B}$ 295 2{,}6 
\end{document}
```

Originally, compiled PDF file looks fine:

[image: test-asanamath-compiled-by-lualatex]

However some latin and greek letters, math symbols disapper after it was saved from within Adobe Acrobat:

[image: test-asanamath-compiled-by-lualatex-and-saved-from-adobe]

This damage does not occur if source file was compiled with the aid of xelatex or if other math fonts is loaded. Here is how saved PDF looks when Cambria Math was used:

[image]

Comment: please give a complete minimal example.

Comment: @Herbert: I added minimal example as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you ran into a bug in Adobe Reader. The MacOS version is known for bugs when using OpenType fonts (e.g. [10.6.7 causes OpenType issues](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/28/10-6-7-update-causes-opentype-font-issues/)).

As a solution when you want to compress the PDF file, you can use the program `ps2pdfwr`, which is a wrapper for ghostscript.

```
ps2pdfwr <inputfile> <outputfile>
```

This is a short-hand for the following:

```
gs -sOutputFile=<outputfile>
   -dNOPAUSE
   -dSAFER
   -sBATCH
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
   <inputfile>
```

Beware: This also recompresses included JPEG images, which may result in quality loss.

Comment: If so, why then there is no evidence of such problem if xetex is used to compile my file?

Comment: XeTeX and LuaTeX employ a different approach when it comes to font handling. XeTeX uses FreeType and Fontconfig, however LuaTeX uses fontforge internally. The final result in the PDF reader should be the same, though the PDF files differ. Apparently the output file of LuaTeX triggers the bug.

Comment: @Macro, how fonts are loaded shouldn't affect the final PDF, but rather how they are embedded in the font; XeTeX uses a separate driver (xdvipdfmx or xdv2pdf) to generate the PDF while LuaTeX has its own "built-in" PDF backend. But you are right, since both are totally different code bases the resulting PDF can be quite different internally.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method how to keep fonts embedded. From **Adobe Acrobat 10** menu select: **File** | **Save As** | **Optimized PDF...** and in the field **Make compartible with** select **Acrobat 9.0 and later** or **Acrobat 10.0 and later** (I did not try other versions).

Unfortunately, this method removes poster images for embedded swf movies (whereas poster images for embedded avi movies are OK). So, this indeed looks as if the problem is caused by inteference of some Asana-Math "features" and Acrobat bugs.