# Asana Math + XeLaTeX: missing math upon resaving or editing in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, opentype, adobe

Related to this question:
[Asana-math + LuaTeX : missing greeks/arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33314/asana-math-luatex-missing-greeks-arrows)

I experienced similar problems with a PDF produced by XeLaTeX (v0.9998) with MiKTeX 2.9 and Adobe Acrobat Pro IX or XI:

The PDF produced by XeLaTeX and opened in Adobe Acrobat looks good and all fonts are embedded including Asana Math. However, after saving with another name or after editing (for example, extracting pages), a lot of Asana Math is replaced by questionmark symbols.

The only solution that worked so far is replacing Asana Math by XITS Math.

PS. I was not sure to post this as a new question or an answer to the question mentioned above. It was assumed in [Asana-math + LuaTeX : missing greeks/arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33314/asana-math-luatex-missing-greeks-arrows) that this is a bug in Adobe. If so, the issue has not been solved, even when using the newest versions of Adobe Acrobat, MiKTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Does the same happen if you use `TG Pagella Math`?

Comment: @egreg I just checked and I don't have TG Pagella Math installed. I am busy right now but will try your suggestion later. As I mentioned, XITS Math seems to work fine.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me: the linked question is clear that this is a problem at the Adobe end, which is likely, and there is not much we could possibly add here.